# Java read file content from cordova index.html

Tags: java, android, cordova

I want to read the file content of cordova asset index.html file using Java. This is the code I am currently using.

```
        Path filePath = Paths.get("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        try {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath, charset);
            for(String line: lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.format("I/O error: %s%n", ex);
        }
```

I get the following error message: I/O error: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/android_asset/www/index.html

I have also tried setting file path to "index.html" and "www/index.html" which also shows the same error. I just don't know which path I have to use here.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is compiled, the structure goes as follow in `app/src/main`

```
  assets/www
  java
  libs
  res
```

So I guess you're trying to target `./../assets/www/index.html` relative to the java folder....

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, and your efforts :) 
I am quite sure the problem was that this was in fact a cordova android application and as soon as I compiled it, the entire file system was android based.
However I was able to solve my problem in a different way - will post that. thx though